# How do I convert ArrayList to interface?

Tags: java

The following code is giving me the error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList to StackInterface". How would I convert or am I using the incorrect data type for ArrayList?

```
public class PostFixStack<T> implements StackInterface<T>
    protected ArrayList<T> elements; // ArrayList that holds stack elements
    public PostFixStack() {elements = new ArrayList<T>();      
}

public int evaluate(String expression){
    Scanner tokenizer = new Scanner(expression);
    StackInterface<Integer> stack = new ArrayList<T>();
```

Comment: `StackInterface` not List type

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is: you don't.

When you turn to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for ArrayList, you find there:

> All Implemented Interfaces:
>
> Serializable, Cloneable, Iterable, Collection, List, RandomAccess

StackInterface isn't there. Thus an ArrayList can **never** be casted to that type.

Thus, you would rather need:

```
StackInterface<Integer> stack = new PostFixStack<>();
```

In other words: the fact that your *stack* implementation class uses an ArrayList is an internal detail of that implementation, and when you want to create one of your stacks, then you instantiate *that* implementation, and not something else!